# TYPO3 multilanguage concept

Tags: typo3, realurl

I need to create two pages trees, each for specific language (not use additional language pages). In my case two pages trees - two languages (German and English). German language shall be by default.

In url language must be added after domain via "/" like this:
 http://www.example.de/de or http://www.example.de/en

Can someone suggest me how I can do this? Please attach some typoscript templates and especialy realurl configuration files.

Earlier I have read on some forums that in this way you can't organize multilanguage website. Is it true? Please give me an advise. I would be very thankful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We are not here to write your code. Please google yourself and ask if you have a specific question.
Keywords to google: "TYPO3 language configuration", "typo3 realurl configuration"

Comment: @Benjamin, I'm sorry. I have asked bad. It was 3:00 am :)  
  In general I would ask if it possible to use separate pages trees for each languages if you have one domaid. And language must be added after the domain via slash, like I have indicated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my experience and knowledge this is not possible with default TYPO3 configuration options.

A idea from be would be to use two sub-trees within the pagetree for example.de

In one sub-tree you have all german pages and in the other sub-tree you have all english pages.

The startpage (rootpage) of this domain is then the only page that is translated normally. On this page the links and menus are configured to point to the right tree based on the current language...

But i advice you to just create a subdomain en.example.de and configure it with its own tree and rootpage. Especially if you are a beginner, this will make live more easy for you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. This is enough information for me about multilanguages in TYPO3.

I tried to do it like this:

- Root page (shortcut to Deutsch)

  - English (shortcut to Home)

    - Home
       ...
  - Deutsch (shortcut to Startseite)

    - Startseite
      ...

But in this case realurl told me something like this (don't remember): Path "startseite" is not in postVarSet.

FYI: I'm not beginner in TYPO3, just didn't develop multilanguages projects before.

Comment: I wouldn´t use shortcuts but instead organize it like:
http://pastebin.com/dEunPsVe

Comment: @Benjamin, thank you very much. But not need this anymore. Customer have agreed with me to use subdomains for language versions.